# image Feature organization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a matrix containing 512 images of size 128 x 128, and I have a program that can take each image and unravel them into 256 blocks and calculate some characteristics for each block.

The program gives me back a feature vector with  size of 131072 x 8, i.e. 8 features for 131072 blocks. What I want is my features to be organized in the following way: having features for each image i.e `Feature = [512 * Number of features for each image]`

Here is the code I wrote:

```
load('bd.mat');
tic
cb = 8; lb = 8;

F = zeros(512*256,8); % features
k=1;
for i=1:512
    tmp = bd(:,:,i);
    tmp = im2col(tmp,[cb,lb],'distinct');%'sliding');
    for j=1:256,
        [a, b, c, d]=dwt2(reshape(tmp(:,j),cb,cb),'db1');
        z = [a(:),b(:),c(:),d(:)];
        F(k,:) = [mean(z), sqrt(sum(z.^2))];
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do here.  What do you mean by `512 * number of features for each image`?  Why 512? What should each new feature represent?  We can't read your mind.  Give us more.

Comment: 512  because I have 512 image in my intiale matrix. I have now as a result  the vector F of the form F [131072 x 8], 131,072 is the total number of bloks in the hole database and 8 is the number of feature by blok. I want to have as a feature vector in the following form: F [512 * number of features]: For each image from the 512 images have the corresponding characteristics . in other words, for each image I have 256 block and 8 feature for each block, I want to bring together the features of all blocks of  an image in an element of the final features vector .

Comment: Why don't you just make the `131072 x 8` matrix into a single vector?  That way, you can create a single vector that is of length `512 x 131072 x 8`?  In that case, after the `j` `for` loop has completed, make this into a single `131072 * 8 x 1` vector, then add this to a final features vector.  I'm just going with how I'm interpreting your question.  I still don't quite understand what you want though.

Comment: effectively, at present i have  a single 131072 * 8  vector. 131072 is the total number of block of my hole database (512 * 256): 256 is the number of blocks per image (i have 512 image). the vector  at the end is of the form  8 * 131072 ie for each block of (131072 blocks) I have 8 features. But me ,  I want the following form: for each image of the 512 images I want to have 8 * 256 features .i want for each initial image assemble the extracted features from its blocks in a single element of the final features vector. 
Thank you very much for your interest